# How to create an alert after 3 confirmations in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[Cross shapes means to sell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by3pZ.png)

Hi all, I have created an indicator, but I'm stuck on how I can create a buy/sell alert after 3 orange cross. Can someone help me with the condition? Thank you!

```
long = longCondition1 and ta.barssince(longCondition1) < 2 and ta.barssince(longCondition1) < 3
plotshape(long, location=location.belowbar, style=shape.cross, size=size.tiny, color=color.rgb(255,192,203))
```

I used it but it's not following the condition that it should be plotted after 3 orange cross.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an alert after three orange crosses in a row, you can do it as follows:

```
long = longCondition1 and longCondition1[1] and longCondition1[2]
```

If you want just the first three then your code should look like this:

```
long = longCondition1 and longCondition1[1] and longCondition1[2] and not longCondition1[3]
```

Comment: However it highlighted everything that follows, is there any way to highlight just that instance after the three orange? Thank you!

Comment: see the edited code